# XLABEL failed to uniformly appear in multiplot subplots with macro

Tags: gnuplot

I am plotting several datafiles within the same frame using the `multiplot` command in gnuplot (version `5.2`). I was able to reproduce the issue I am facing with this code below where for instance instead of datafiles I am plotting simple `sin`-functions.

**Code**

```
reset session

# ****** margins *****
if (!exists("MP_LEFT")) MP_LEFT = 0.1
if (!exists("MP_RIGHT")) MP_RIGHT = 0.95
if (!exists("MP_BOTTOM")) MP_BOTTOM = 0.075
if (!exists("MP_TOP")) MP_TOP = 0.925
if (!exists("MP_GAP")) MP_GAP = 0.025

# ****** Macros *****
XLABEL = "set xlabel '{/:Italic=20 x}' offset graph 0, 0.3"
NOXLABEL = "unset xlabel"
NOXTICS = "set format x ''"
NOYTICS = "set format y ''"
OBJECT = "unset object; set object circle at graph 0, 0 radius scr 0.1"
set terminal pngcairo 
set termoption font "Times, 12"
set output "test.png"
    set multiplot layout 2, 2 rowsfirst \
        margins scr MP_LEFT, MP_RIGHT, MP_BOTTOM, MP_TOP \
        spacing scr MP_GAP 
        @NOXLABEL
        @XLABEL
        @NOXTICS
        @NOYTICS
        @OBJECT
        plot sin(x) w l title "sin(x)"
        @NOXLABEL
        @XLABEL
        @NOXTICS
        @NOYTICS
        plot sin(x + pi/4) w l title "sin(x + {/Symbol p}/4)"
        @NOXLABEL
        @XLABEL
        @OBJECT
        @NOXTICS
        @NOYTICS
        plot sin(x + pi/2) w l title "sin(x + {/Symbol p}/2)"
        @NOXLABEL
        @XLABEL
        @OBJECT
        @NOXTICS
        @NOYTICS
        plot sin(x + pi) w l title "sin(x + {/Symbol p})"
    unset multiplot 
unset output
```

Macros are very useful in multiplot as it helps to share similar commands across all the subplots as I am doing for instance with the macro `OBJECT`. However, here I failed to understand why the offset I am chosing for the xlabels using the macro `XLABEL` creates different shifts with respect to the `xaxis` on the different subplots, especially the ones in (line:1, col:1) and (line:2, col:1) in the result below.

**Result**

[image: Result of code run]

Can anyone help fix the misbehavior of the xlabel in the macro? 
An explanation of the issue is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix the behaviour if you use e.g. `offset screen 0,0.15` or `offset 0,4` instead of `offset graph 0.3`. 
This might fix the issue but does not explain the unexpected behaviour with `offset graph`. A bug? At least something with origins and sizes of sub-plots in a multiplot environment. But this has nothing to do with the macro itself. Check the following further minimized examples.

**Code 1:**

```
reset session
set multiplot layout 2,2 rowsfirst
    set xlabel "x label" offset graph 0, 0.3
    plot x
    plot x
    plot x
    plot x
unset multiplot
```

**Result 1:**

[image]

**Code 2:**

```
reset session
set multiplot layout 2,2 rowsfirst
    set xlabel "x label" offset screen 0, 0.15
    plot x
    plot x
    plot x
    plot x
unset multiplot
```

**Result 2:**

[image]

Comment: it worked perfectly. I also think the same on this issue. Anyway, thanks.